# Processing files stored on cloud (S3 or Spaces)

Tags: python, django, openpyxl, django-storage

I've setup a script to process excel files uploaded by a user. The scripts works fine when the file is stored on the local disk.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("file_path.xlsx")  # Load workbook from disk works fine
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

I've then setup `django-storages` to allow user uploaded files to be stored on digital ocean spaces.

My problem now is how to access and process the cloud stored file. For the record, if I pass the file URL to `load_workbook` it fails with the error `No such file or directory: file_url`.

Do I have to download the file using `requests` and then process it as a local file? Feels inefficient? What options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get byte content of the file, wrap it in `ContentFile` and pass it to `openpyxl`. Assuming your model is `FileContainer` and field name is `file`:

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fc = FileContainer.objects.first()
bytefile = fc.file.read()
wb = load_workbook(ContentFile(bytefile))
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

I checked it with S3 and it works just fine.

If you want to actually save file locally, you can try this:

```py
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fc = FileContainer.objects.first()
local_storage = FileSystemStorage()

bytefile = fc.file.read()
newfile = ContentFile(bytefile)

relative_path = local_storage.save(fc.file.name, newfile)

wb = load_workbook(local_storage.path(relative_path))
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for Digital Ocean's Spaces also. For small files I believe it will suffice. Would you change it to allow it to be more efficient for large files (100-400 MB range)?

Comment: For large files I would rather download file and save it with default [`FileSysteStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/files/storage/#the-filesystemstorage-class). Not via `requests` but native django functionality, to keep AWS credentials and flexibility.

Comment: A few minutes of reviewing the Django link and quick googling and am not sure how I'd go about using `FileStystemStorage` to download and save the file. Can you provide snippet or a link to show how to accomplish this?

Comment: @lukik I started to doubt that it is better solution, but anyway attached it for reference. Couldn't think of another solution without `ContentFile`. Don't forget to delete file afterwards.

Comment: @lukik another option would be to download file from S3 via low-level `boto3` library (that is used underneath `django-storages`) and then open it directly. No django files API would be used.